# Cannot Use Destructuring Assignment In Vuex Mutation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

EDIT: I realised Vuex may allow directly mutating state in mutations, as opposed to treating state as immutable in Redux mutations. If this is the case, which most of my research resulted in people saying this is okay to do, then I can avoid what was my previous requirement of using destructuring assignment in the first place.

---

**Problem**: Vuex seems to throw an error while collecting modules if I use destructuring assignment within a module's mutation.

**What I've Tried**: Commenting out the destructuring assignment removes the error.

**Observations**: The mutation is never called, or at least placed `console.log` messages are never logged.

**Versions**: vuex@3.1.2, vue@2.6.10, node v10.17.0

```js
removeItem (state, id) {
    const { [id]: unused, ...rest } = state.items
    state.items = rest
}
```

```
vuex.common.js:272 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined
    at vuex.common.js:272
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at assertRawModule (vuex.common.js:271)
    at ModuleCollection.register (vuex.common.js:197)
    at vuex.common.js:211
    at vuex.common.js:80
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at forEachValue (vuex.common.js:80)
    at ModuleCollection.register (vuex.common.js:210)
    at new ModuleCollection (vuex.common.js:171)
```

To isolate what I think is causing the problem, syntactically this causes an error in Vuex:

```js
removeItem (state, id) {
    const { [id]: unused, ...rest } = state.items
}
```

But this does not:

```js
removeItem (state, id) {
    const { [id]: unused } = state.items
}
```

I've found we are transpiling with browserify, which yields the following:

```js
removeReadyHelp: function removeReadyHelp(state, name) {
    var _state$items = state.items,
        unused = _state$items[name],
        rest = _objectWithoutProperties(_state$items, [name]);
}

...

function _objectWithoutProperties(obj, keys) {
    var target = {};
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (keys.indexOf(i) >= 0) continue;
        if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, i)) continue;
        target[i] = obj[i];
    }
    return target;
}
```

The following code is the entire vuex module. The mutation in question is `removeAvailableHelp` (the mutation above `removeItem` is edited to be generic.)

```js
import helpApi from '../../api/api-viewed-help.js'

/**
 * Info about available help necessary for triggering it from the help list.
 * @typedef {object} Help 
 * @property {string} Help.name Uid name of help.
 * @property {HelpTrigger} Help.trigger 
 */

/**
 * Function to call that should trigger the available help in the help list.
 * @callback HelpTrigger 
 * @returns {void}
 */

export const module = {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        viewedHelpNames: [],
        availableHelp: {},
        hydrated: false
    },
    actions: {
        /**
         * Hydrate vuex state from database.
         * @param {*} vuex
         * @param {string} usercode Usercode to fetch viewed help by.s
         */
        async hydrate ({ commit }, usercode) {
            const viewedHelpNames = await helpApi.getAllViewedHelpNames(usercode)
            commit('_setViewedHelpNames', viewedHelpNames)
            commit('_hydrated')
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        /**
         * Set all viewed help names to passed array.
         * @param {*} state
         * @param {string[]} viewedHelpNames
         */
        _setViewedHelpNames (state, viewedHelpNames) {
            state.viewedHelpNames = viewedHelpNames
        },
        _hydrated (state) {
            state.hydrated = true
        },
        /**
         * @param {*} state Vuex
         * @param {Help} help 
         */
        addAvailableHelp (state, help) {
            state.availableHelp[help.name] = help
        },
        removeAvailableHelp (state, name) {
            const { [name]: unused, ...res } = state.availableHelp
            state.availableHelp = res
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dylan, Usually this problem occur if you don't pass store. could you please ensure stored is passed

new Vue({
  ...
  store,
  ...
})

Comment: @prasana The store is passed into the Vue instance.

Comment: The 'rest' feature is a later addition to the syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring If you're using Babel you may want to check whether you have this feature enabled. I doubt the problem is specific to Vuex mutations, more likely you'll find that trying to use this syntax anywhere in your code won't work correctly.

Comment: @skirtle We are using browserify. I did find that the function is being transpiled. I've added it to the question. I'm not sure if that is causing the problem.

Comment: could you please try this
 
 removeAvailableHelp (state, name) {
            const res = {...state.availableHelp};
            delete res[name];
            state.availableHelp = res;
        }

Comment: @prasanakannan Yes, that results in no errors.

Comment: so is there any restriction in using that?

Comment: @prasanakannan There are various alternative ways to implement the code. Perhaps I missed the point but I thought the question we were trying to answer is why the original code (which appears to be valid) isn't working.

Comment: @skirtle, Yeah got it. The code seems to be perfectly fine.  could you please provide version details of your transpiler your using

Answer (score 1):

One-way to overcome this issue would be to using `delete` operator but make sure ur not mutating the object by taking a deep clone of that.

```js
removeAvailableHelp (state, name) { 
  const res = {...state.availableHelp}; 
  delete res[name]; 
  state.availableHelp = res; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your destructuring is a little bit different of what it should be.
the correct way would be like this:

```
removeItem (state, id) {
  const { id: unused, ...rest } = state.items
  state.items = rest
}
```

Since your id should be aliased to unused, then you don't need the brackets around the id

as far as I can, I'm adding a example I did on devtools

```
const state = {
  id: 2308147,
  description: "hello world",
  beaconId: "1248ad890"
}

const { id: unused, ...rest} = state // unused: 2308147, rest: {description: 'hello world', beaconId: "1248ad890"}
state.items = rest
console.log(state) // { beaconId: "1248ad890", description: "hello world", id: 2308147, items: Object { description: "hello world", beaconId: "1248ad890" }
```

Comment: I believe the original intent was for `id` to be dynamic. The use of square brackets is appropriate in that case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring

Comment: @skirtle Correct, id is a dynamic property name. In chrome devtools this operation does work fine. The problem occurs when I use it in a vuex mutation.